# Wordpress Custom WP_QUERY: empty anchor tag?

Tags: wordpress

I have a Custom WP_Query:

```
    $args = array(
    'category_name'     => 'direct-naar',
    'post_type'        => array( 'page', 'post' ),
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);

$directNaarPosts = new WP_Query( $args );

?>  

<section id="side-direct_naarlist" class="widget widget_text">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
        <h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">Direct naar:</h4>
        <div class="category-direct-naar"><?php
if( $directNaarPosts->have_posts() ):
    while( $directNaarPosts->have_posts() ): $directNaarPosts->the_post();
        $title      = get_the_title();
        $permalink  = get_permalink();
    ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>" title="Ga naar <?php echo $title;?>">
                <?php echo $title; ?>
            </a>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
echo '</div></div></section>';
```

Which produces following code:

```
<div class="category-direct-naar"><a>
            </a><a href="http://wp.kndb.nl/damclub-zoeken/#damclub-zoeken">Damclub zoeken</a>
            <a href="http://wp.kndb.nl/nationale-competitie/#nationale-competitie">Nationale competitie</a>
            <a href="http://wp.kndb.nl/downloads/#downloads">Downloads</a>
            <a href="http://wp.kndb.nl/damclubs-nl/#damclubs-nl">Damclubs NL</a>
            <a href="http://wp.kndb.nl/damkalender/#damkalender">Damkalender</a>
</div>
```

See also the right sidebar on: http://wp.kndb.nl/category/sport/

After the `<div class="category-direct-naar">` there is an empty anchor tag. I have no idea where this anchor tag come from.

Can somebody help me with this anoying problem?

Comment: I have found the solution of this problem. In the HTML code above this query i have closed an anchor tag the wrong way :-(. This was causing the problem. Maybe this is helpful for somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of this problem. In the HTML code above this query i have closed an anchor tag the wrong way :-(. This was causing the problem. Maybe this is helpful for somebody in the future